# Locked out of SSH on LAMP server but have SFTP access

Tags: rescue, system-recovery

I made a mistake in `/etc/sshd_config` so have locked myself out of my remotely hosted server running Centos 6.

It's running Apache and I have FTP access to `/var/www` and I know the root password.

To try to restore `sshd_config` I have tried creating a PHP page with a few `exec()` and `passthru()` commands - these run as user `apache`. I have tried:

```
echo "password" | su -c "cp -f sshd_config /etc/sshd/sshd_config"
```

but that didn't work. `expect` is not installed on the server.

Does anyone know a way of resolving this?

Comment: What mistake did you do in ssh_config?

Comment: Do you have FTP or SFTP access? The title and the contents of your Q are disagreeing with each other.

Comment: SFTP. The sshd_config is pointing to a hostkey file that does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Does root have SFTP access?  Can you `sftp root@remote`?  If so, you should be able to download the /etc/sshd/sshd_config from the remote to your local machine, fix it, and push the corrected version back.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a server you setup, or is it something a hosting provider supplied? If the hosting provider supplied it, do they offer a method of installing Webmin?

If not, what exactly did you change in your SSH configuration?

Comment: Hosting provider set up. No they don't offer webmin.